# Getting the "Database cannot be opened. It is in the middle of a restore.", when using a different database

Tags: sql-server, restore, sql-server-2019

#### Problem

We have an everyday process of restoring a DB from backups to kind of replicate it on another server (yes, I know it's not the way to do that) and encountered a rather strange problem. Process goes like so:

1. We have 2 databases named DBNAME, one on server1 and one on server2
2. We get the backup of DBNAME from server1 to restore it on server2 (from here only server2 is in use)
3. We start restoring the backup on server2 into DBNAME_temp
4. It's in restore for a while
5. We drop DBNAME on server2 and rename DBNAME_temp to DBNAME

The problem is, while the process is on step 4, we start getting *random* errors "Database 'DBNAME_temp' cannot be opened. It is in the middle of a restore. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 927)." for scripts and procs that never referenced DBNAME_temp, only DBNAME.
For exmple, there's a  `select * from DBNAME.dbo.table` inside a proc and it will fail with the mentioned error. By *random* I mean that other procs referencing DBNAME will be just fine, as well as ad-hoc queries. And failed procs may also run without errors next time.

#### Steps so far

Option RECOMPILE does help, but I don't want to shove it in every possible proc with DBNAME in it. I thought that the problem is in the cached plans that somehow stored info  about the wrong DB, but the failing procs seem to be using the same plans both on fail and on succeful run the next day.

Comment: Are the procedures causing the error always the same (despite the fact that they work sometimes)?

Comment: @Ronaldo Hard to say, there're a lot of procdures using that db and for now we see new ones in the erorr log from time to time.

Comment: Maybe you could monitor that with extended events. That way you would map the ones throwing the error and possibly see some pattern that will help you find the root cause.

Comment: Please add your restore script to your Post. There are options during restore that affect the original database, even when restoring to a separately named database.

Comment: It almost sounds like you are trying to rename it while it is still restoring it.